# Creating a list of instances(objects) of a class in Python without explicit list comprehension or for loops

Tags: python, list-comprehension, vectorization

The goal here is to have a class (let's say Teachers) that has a single attribute (score) as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
maxScore = 10
numTeach = 50

class Teacher:

    counter = 0

    def __init__(self, score):
         self.score = score
    
    # code to keep track of the number of objects created
    Teacher.counter += 1
    
    def get(self):
        return self.score
```

How could I create a randomly-variable-length list of instances (objects) of this class Teacher without using any list comprehension (maybe from vectorization or broadcasting?)

I have the following code that suffices in terms of results, but is not the solution I am hoping to use:

```
teacher_list = [Teacher(np.random.randint(1,maxScore+1)) for i in range(np.random.randint(1, numTeach+1))]
```

Then I want to be able to take the mean of the scores attribute for all of the (random number less than or equal to numTeach) instances of the Teacher class in teacher_list (again ideally without list comprehension). I have this in place now:

```
np.mean([Teacher.score for Teacher in teacher_list])
```

But is there a better way to achieve this same result without using list comprehension?

After review, it seems the methods I used revolving around list comprehension are the clearest and most concise way to achieve the result I am after.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a list comprehension?  What you show has no downside that I can think of.

Comment: You're asking to do this without list comprehension, yet you're using list comprehension in your examples? Also, if this is working for you, but you want another way, why do you want another way? What is the ultimate goal here? What do you expect to achieve?

Comment: You might find some function that seems to perform this same action without a list comprehension or loop, but it is likely using one itself, so you're just hiding its use.  And a list comprehension is basically just syntactic sugar over a loop, so it's all a loop anyway. - You could hide that call yourself...just create a `createRandomTeacherList` function and hide the list comprehension in there.  I can't think of anything more readable or precise than that.

Comment: This is a small part of a larger project I am working on for class, and this was the solution that I came up with. Then upon further review of the project document, my prof asks that "Your program should NOT contain any for loop or any for clause or any explicit list comprehension or any if statement" so I was curious as to why (I think my solution is better, is that right?) and what other options there might be

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help though! I also agree it look pretty nice and clean. Maybe I will submit and then have a conversation with him about it.

Comment: Bravo!  I think that's the right answer.  You deserve to know why an instructor is preventing you from using a basic feature of the language you're learning.  Until you do know why, I don't see how it can be beneficial to do so.

Comment: I find this question interesting in terms of how it should be approached by the community.  I have therefore put it on Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357876/should-questions-of-the-form-how-can-i-do-a-without-using-x-or-y-for-some-reaso

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for, for the first part of your question, is `np.fromfunction`:

```
np.fromfunction (lambda x: Teacher (np.random.randint(1,maxScore+1)), (100,)
```

That will create an array with 100 elements; each element will be populated with the output of calling the lambda function, which in turn creates a Teacher object with a random value.

Comment: But the OP wants a random length list

Comment: @Steve, the OP wants 'without list comprehension'.  The snippet is not a complete solution for all his problems; it focuses on the piece that the OP stated they're interested in on this question.

Comment: An answer isn't an answer if it only answers half the question.  The OP says quite clearly that they want "a randomly-variable-length list of instances (objects)".  What if your proposed method has no way to produce a list of random length?  Then it is useless to the OP.  Can it?

Comment: @Steve, I'm thinking on whether I change my answer according to your suggestion or not.  The crux of the OP's submission is not the random part, it is the list comprehension.  Adding the random part will make the answer more complete, yes, but also more complex.  Is it worth it?

Comment: The OP has already demostrated they can get a random size list, and they seem able to replace that hardcoded `100` by a randomly generated number.  The answer, less than a service 'fix my problem', is a piece of knowledge for future users of the site.  On that, a less-complex answer may have more value than a more complete one

Comment: I guess it's a matter of opinion.  Seems to me that answering the question "how do I do A + B in a different way?" with "do A' instead" just seems wrong to me.  Why don't you just add a call to `randint` and be done with it? - Then you'll have edited the answer and I can remove my downvote.

Comment: It sounds like an interesting discussion.  I put it on Meta for inputs:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357872/complete-versus-complex

Answer (score -1):

I can't see how vectorization or broadcasting would help here.

While it isn't clear why you would want to avoid list comprehension or explicit loops, what you're trying to do can be achieved with a builtin that loops internally, e.g. `map`. This answers your question but please note that this is not good practice because it kills readability.

So

```py
teacher_list = [Teacher(np.random.randint(1,maxScore+1)) for i in range(np.random.randint(1, numTeach+1))]
```

becomes

```py
teacher_list = list(map(lambda i: Teacher(np.random.randint(1,maxScore+1)), range(np.random.randint(1, numTeach+1))))
```

As for the second question, `np.mean` requires an array (or regular Python list) meaning you could do the `map` trick again:

```py
np.mean(list(map(lambda t: t.score, teacher_list)))
```

Comment: What is `i` for in the lambda?  Would you use this rather than a list comprehension or suggest that someone else do so?  If so, then why?

Comment: As clearly stated, this is not good practice (therefore not recommended) but this answers OP's question. `i` is a dummy parameter because `map` requires the function to take an argument. It could be named `_` instead, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: But we don't yet know WHY the OP wants something different.  This may be no better an alternative, and in real life, it's arguably worse.  We don't want to encourage any sort of obfuscated programming, or "how do I do something this way just for the hell of it?" questions.  We have to think about future seekers who will come along later.  Suggesting a potential solution to an ill-defined question is not helpful to the larger cause.  It might lead a beginner astray.

Comment: I do not disagree that OP's question is bogus - there's no better way indeed. That's not a reason not to try and answer it anyway. Nonetheless, I did leave a disclaimer for OP and future seekers.

Comment: I agree that the question is bogus - it was a requirement of my professor to not use list comprehension, that i didn't not notice until after completing the project. I think that my solution is better than what he is asking for, is that right?

Comment: @NacibNeme - You're wrong when you say "there's not a reason to try to answer the question".  It has been stated many times by moderators and senior SO people that bad questions can only have bad answers.  A question shouldn't be answered until it is at least fully understood.  Hearing "the teacher says that we should do it this way" now makes your answer a little better.  But I still think it's a bad thing, since I don't think we want to encourage answering questions that say "I have to do this this way, even though I don't know why".  "Because my teacher said so" is not real-world helpful.

Comment: @Steve I apologize I am still new to coding world in general, I am a mechanical engineer by trade, so I have little practice at all with python or coding in general outside of a classroom setting. I thought perhaps he was trying to suggest that there was a better method than using list comprehension while not actually saying what it was. I looked around for a while and everything I read points to list comprehension as the way to go, which is why I was curious if there actually IS a better way or not. Seems pretty clear there is no better way. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @mlb193 - you've done nothing wrong.  You don't need to apologize, at least here.  This thread of comments is about this particular answer.  I don't think it's clear that there is no better answer.  I wouldn't stake my life on it.  If the person presenting this answer could explain why it's better, that would be great, and this would be a good answer if they were right or wrong.  But they admit it's an inferior answer.  At that point, I think it doesn't belong here at all.  That's what we were discussing.  I admit I could be wrong about all of it.  I'm just voicing my opinion.